# Using Net::FTP with Perl and trying different commands

Tags: perl, networking, cpan

For testing purposes on my end, I need to write a program that uses [`Net::FTP`][Net::FTP] to connect to a server, and then receives a file in a certain directory. Once it is received, put it right back in that same spot.

Here is my code:

```
   #!/usr/bin/perl

   use Net::FTP;

   $host = "serverA";
   $username = "test";
   $password = "ftptest123";
   $ftpdir = "/ftptest";
   $file = "ftptest.txt";

   $ftp = Net::FTP->new($host) or die "Error connecting to $host: $!";

   $ftp->login($username,$password) or die "Login failed: $!";

   $ftp->cwd($ftpdir) or die "Can't go to $ftpdir: $!";

   $ftp->get($file) or die "Can't get $file: $!";

   $ftp->put($file) or die "Can't put $file: $!";

   $ftp->quit or die "Error closing ftp connection: $!";
```

Any ideas on how to go about this? It seems to run fine, but when it hits the `put` statement it shoots out this at me:

```
[Net::FTP]: https://metacpan.org/module/Net::FTP
```

Comment: You should also begin your perl scripts with "use strict;use warnings;"

Answer (score 1):

check the error message in `$ftp->message`, not in `$!`. It'll probably tell you you don't have wrote access to the directory, or aren't allowed to overwrite an existing file...

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should *always* `use strict` and `use warnings`, and declare all your variables at their first point of use using `my`. That way many trivial errors that you would otherwise ovrelooked will be highlighted for you.

The documentation for `Net::FTP` is incomplete in that it doesn't supply any information on the `message` method. However it is clear from the synopsis that information on any error can be accessed using `$ftp->message`.

Of course this doesn't apply to the constructor, as if that fails there is no object to provide the `message` method, so in this case the information appears in the built-in variable `$@`.

Try this variation on your program. It will probably tell you immediately why it is failing.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::FTP;

my $host = 'serverA';
my $username = 'test';
my $password = 'ftptest123';
my $ftpdir = '/ftptest';
my $file = 'ftptest.txt';

my $ftp = Net::FTP->new($host) or die "Error connecting to $host: $@";

$ftp->login($username,$password) or die "Login failed: ", $ftp->message;

$ftp->cwd($ftpdir) or die "Can't go to $ftpdir: ", $ftp->message;

$ftp->get($file) or die "Can't get $file: ", $ftp->message;

$ftp->put($file) or die "Can't put $file: ", $ftp->message;

$ftp->quit or die "Error closing ftp connection: ", $ftp->message;
```

Comment: +1 for use strict, use warnings and for an example with complete error checking